# QGIS update svg marker symbols

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg

In QGIS (2.14.5LTR) when having an svg marker symbol it is not updated when editing it in inkscape and saving it to the same name/location. Even when switching to another svg symbol and then switching back to the one before, the old version of the symbol is displayed and not the one just edited. And simply loading the new version does not work too (the old one is still kept).

Obviously, QGIS is caching svg symbols, so the question:

- is there a way to clear the 'svg symbol cache' (or however it is called)?
- or is there a way to 'update' the editited symbols (a hidden 'refresh' button or slt)?

Answer (score 4):

Only method I found to work was to use the **Date defined override** option:

[image: Data defined override]

Then funnily enough, copy the path of the same svg and type it in the expression as a string (remove any forward-double slashes):

```
'C:/Users/You/.qgis2/svg/Arrow_01.svg'
```

This updates the svg apparently. Tested on QGIS 2.14.3 and 2.18.0.

Comment: i) as stated, unc paths like `//myserver/the/file.svg` don't work (double slashes)  - ii) the above method seems only to work once: Next time the svg is edited, neither turning on/of data defined override nor re-saving the expression has an effect - iii) the only thing that helps as far as I see is quit QGIS and reopen the project - iv) one thing that helps is to add little amount to the symbol size, say `0.000001`. Then a new symbol is cached. but resetting the size to the original value returns to the old symbol, all in all not very promising...  :-(

Comment: @JochenSchwarze - Shame :( . Perhaps post a [feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) for this? Couldn't find an existing request for this problem.

Comment: ok https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15892

Comment: There's been allready a bug report on this: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13565

Comment: @JochenSchwarze - Good find, I sometimes find it difficult to search for existing bugs on that website...

Comment: not my merit to be honest... Nyall Dawson gave the hint when he closed my request...